# Rails object both belongs_to and has_one

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I'm having a trouble with grasping a proper relationship between two Rails/ActiveRecord classes.

I have a User, which can both create a Slip and simultaneously be an addressee of another slip. Each user can create any number of slips but only one user as the addressee of a given slip.

From the db perspective I have two integer (key) columns for 'user_id' (author) and 'addressee' in the slips table and no reference on the users table.

This is my current approach which is not working at all:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :slips
  belongs_to :slips, :foreign_key => 'addressee'
end

class Slip < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  has_one :addressee, :through => :user
end
```

Please direct me to the proper way of binding these objects.
Thanks and have a nice day!

Answer (score 1):

It should look something like this (the second one could just be called 'slip' but I've called it 'addressor_slip' to avoid confusion):

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :slips
  has_one :addressor_slip, :class_name=> 'Slip', :foreign_key => 'addressee'
end

class Slip < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :addressee, :class_name=> 'User', :foreign_key => 'addressee'
end
```

You could also create an association from User to User through :addressor_slip

Answer (score 0):

Look at `many to many` relationships here: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html

You're probably looking for `has_and_belongs_to_many`.